# MySQL - add two dates and set equal to some days

Tags: mysql

I want to check that lastdate to today is equal to 75 days or not. If it is equal then return 1 else return 0.

I tried below query which gives error-

```
 Select (DATE_ADD(Last_date,CURDATE())=75 DAY) from assessment;
```

Please give me correct query to get the result-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `CASE` expression with [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
Select 
   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Last_date,CURDATE()) = 75 then 1 else 0 END AS col
from assessment
```

**Note that:** If `last_date` might be before or after the `CUR_DATE`, in this case you will get a negative results. Because:

> **DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days**

So, you might need to get the absolute value of the difference using `ABS`:

```
Select 
   CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(Last_date,CURDATE()) = 75 then 1 else 0 END) AS col
from assessment
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MySQL DATEDIFF function

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp